# Input textbox showing <?php.... ?> when value='<?php... ?>' />

Tags: php, html

Hie there,

I'm trying to do a search engine but when i put this code in

```
<form action='./Search3.php' method='POST'>
<input type='text' id='Searchform' name='Searchform' size='40' value='<?php echo $_POST['Searchform']; ?>' />

<input type='Submit' value='Search' >
```

My input box return as such

[image]

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's a PHP-file?

Comment: Are you sure that the server is configured correctly?

Comment: save your file with filename.php. looks like it is html file.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to put php code into pure html file. Guys above are right.

Comment: I've saved the file under php....

file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Search3.php

Comment: You have Syntax Problem use double quotes  " " 
ex -:

<?php echo $_POST["SearchForm"]; ?>

Comment: have you started the xampp server?

Comment: Have started my xampp server and stuff...

Comment: OK! Yup, it was solved because of my server settings. It didnt execute the php somehow.... change the settings as suggested... Thanks for helping out guys.